# Getting error while retrieving json array object using jsonpath in karate

Tags: karate, jsonpath

I am getting error while retrieving values A,B, C using jsonpath

Error:

```
karate.jsonPath(response, "$.code[*~]"), com.jayway.jsonpath.InvalidPathException: Expected wildcard token to end with ']'
```

- def value = karate.jsonPath(response, "$.code[*~]")
- def value_expected = ["A","B","C"]
- match value contains only value_expected

Response is as below:

```
 {
      "code": {
        "A": [
          {
            "codeValue": 510575,
            "Key": "XYZ"
          }
        ],
        "B": [
          {
            "codeValue": 510575,
            "Key": "XYZ"
          }
        ],
        "C": [
          {
            "codeValue": 510575,
            "Key": "XYZ"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend JsonPath for cases like this, e.g. getting keys, it is really hard. Please use the Karate JSON transforms: [github](https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms)

```
* def keys = []
* def fun = function(k, v){ karate.appendTo(keys, k) }
* karate.forEach(response.code, fun)
* match keys == ['A', 'B', 'C']
```